# Go directive in go.mod not being honored

Tags: go

I have an application where I want to enforce Go v1.19, so I specified `go 1.19` in `go.mod` file expecting that any system where go version is < 1.19 will observe failure while building.

But it seems, that is not the case. I have another system with `Go v1.16.5` and `go build` command succeeded there as well. The application is running with `v1.16`

Is the `Go directive` in `go.mod` file just advisory ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your version of Go, it is advisory. Here's what the documentation says:

> The go directive sets the minimum version of Go required to use this module. Before Go 1.21, the directive was advisory only; now it is a mandatory requirement: Go toolchains refuse to use modules declaring newer Go versions.

The full documentation is here: https://go.dev/ref/mod

Comment: Yes, I read that one. It just says that specifying the directive is mandatory. But it doesn't say if the directive itself is honored

Comment: It says for versions >=21, "The go line declares a required minimum version of Go to use with this module." It also says "Go toolchains refuse to use modules declaring newer Go versions.". Based on this, there is not much you can enforce.

Comment: What would this statement mean "Go toolchains refuse to use modules declaring newer Go versions" ?

Comment: What I read from that is if you build a module depending on others that require higher versions of Go, it won't work. In other words, your Go toolchain will only work if the transitive closure of all dependencies has smaller or equal versions to that of the toolchain's. I did not verify this myself.

Comment: @mittal: The section for the [go directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go) explains  each use case in detail. It can affect the behavior of the `go` command and which features may be available depending on the version specified.